# How to get Corner Cordinates from Visible Windows Phone 8 Map

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary, bing-maps

I am using Windows Phone 8 Map, in that i have to find corner coordinates (Longitude, Latitude) of Visible map.

How to get those coordinates point.

Map Namespace `xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"`

XAML : `<maps:Map Name="mapStalkerAlert" Height="240" BorderBrush="#CA3498" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3"/>`

[image]

Comment: You can find your ans here [How to get coordinates of corners of visible bing map?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801943/how-to-get-coordinates-of-corners-of-visible-bing-map

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone 8 & 8.1 there isn't a simple property that has this information. That said I have come up with a solution for WP8.1 here: [Get view bounds of a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468236/get-view-bounds-of-a-map/24469837#24469837)

You should be able to port this over to WP8.